# accessing a module from a package whose init file imports that module via AS keyword

Tags: python, import, package, python-import, python-packaging

Sorry for the confusing title. I tried at least! Here is my directory structure:

```
root\
    mypackage\
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
    main.py
```

**mymodule.py**

```py
print('inside mymodule.py')
```

**__init__.py**

```py
print('inside __init__')
from . import mymodule as m
```

**main.py**

```py
import mypackage
print(mypackage.m)
print(mypackage.mymodule)  # <--- Why does it work?
```

and the output:

```
inside __init__
inside mymodule.py
<module 'mypackage.mymodule' from 'C:\\Users...\\mypackage\\mymodule.py'>
<module 'mypackage.mymodule' from 'C:\\Users...\\mypackage\\mymodule.py'>
```

in `main.py` file, when I import `mypackage`, this label actually refers to the `__init__.py` file, so I can access all the objects/labels inside that module. It makes sense that  `mypackage.m` works because `m` is now a symbol inside the `__init__.py`'s global namespace.

But there is no `mymodule` key/symbol inside `__init__.py`'s namespace because I rebind the `mymodule` symbol to `m` label via `as m`.

**question:** So why this `print(mypackage.mymodule)` works without throwing any exception?

Additional information : If I have another module inside the package, let's say `temp.py`, then `print(mypackage.temp)` won't work because again `mypackage` refers to `__init__.py`.
Also it's interesting for me that if I write `print(mymodule)` inside the `__init__.py` and I run the `main.py` module, it will run correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

After two days playing with import statements and searching the document I found the answer. First I'm going to tell the reason why this is happening, then I explain it in much more details. (**Also see the update section at the bottom**)

Look at this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) from the document, also check the structure tree mentioned in the example in that link:

> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement `from sound.effects import *`
> does not import all submodules from the package `sound.effects` into the
> current namespace; it only ensures that the package `sound.effects` has
> been imported (possibly running any initialization code in
> `__init__.py`) and then imports **whatever names are defined in the package**. This includes any names defined (**and submodules explicitly
> loaded**) by `__init__.py`.

It is not important how we import the `mypackage` package in `main.py`, either `import mypackage` or `from mypackage import *` form doesn't matter.

By doing so, Python imports all the names defined in the `__init__.py` module like the `m` we saw above, *also* the submodule explicitly loaded (here `mymodule` module). Properly speaking it adds `'mymodule'` key to the `__init__.py`'s global namespace.

### Let's see this in more details:

I'm going to change `__init__.py` a little bit so that we can run it directly as a *main* module (Since we used relative import inside we can not do that) then I'm going to print what is inside it's global namespace. (Don't forget to add the `mypackage` directory with PYTHONPATH)

```py
# __init__.py
print('inside __init__')
from mypackage import mymodule as m
print("--------------------------------")
for k, v in globals().copy().items():
    if not k.startswith('__'):
        print(k)
```

output :

```
inside __init__
inside __init__
inside mymodule.py
--------------------------------
mymodule
m
--------------------------------
m
```

You see `"inside __init__"` print statement two times because this file is executed two times, once by itself and then by executing this line : `from mypackage import mymodule as m`

It's obvious that under the dashed lines, we got different outputs. First one both `mymodule` and `m`, second one only `m`.

When we run `__init__.py` directly, a record is added to the `sys.modules` named `'__main__'`. But when we import `mypackage`, another record is added to the `sys.modules` named `mypackage`. The interesting part is both of them points to the same file in the same location **BUT** the module objects that are created from these files are not the same.

To demonstrate this, I'm going to add a few lines of code inside `mymodule.py`. This help us seeing these file and modules:

```py
# mymodule.py
print('inside mymodule.py')

import sys
v1 = sys.modules['mypackage']
v2 = sys.modules['__main__']
print(v1)
print(v2)
print(f'v1 is v2: {v1 is v2}')
print(f'v1 == v2: {v1 == v2}')
print(f'v1.__dict__ == v2.__dict__: {v1.__dict__ == v2.__dict__}')
print('mypackage', list(v1.__dict__))
print('__main__', list(v2.__dict__))
```

Now let's run `__init__.py` module directly again!

```
inside __init__
inside __init__
inside mymodule.py
<module 'mypackage' from 'C:\\Users...\\mypackage\\__init__.py'> # these are the same
<module '__main__' from 'C:\\Users...\\mypackage\\__init__.py'> # these are the same 
v1 is v2: False
v1 == v2: False
v1.__dict__ == v2.__dict__: False
mypackage ['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__path__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__']
__main__ ['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__file__', '__cached__']
--------------------------------
mymodule
m
--------------------------------
m
```

As the output shows, they are not the same at all. `v1` is package because it has `__path__`.

The only case when Python adds `'mymodule'` key to the `__init__.py`'s namespace is when we import `import mypackage` and it loads all the submodules that explicitly loaded by `__init__.py`.

---

#### Update:

I've found a page from documentation which addresses this exactly:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism, a binding is placed in
> the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object.